# Snipping tool to take a snapshot of login screen

Tags: gratis, windows-7, screenshot, login

I am not sure if it is possible but is there a way to screenshot my login screen or take a snapshot of it whilst still being logged in on my useraccount?

Is there a program for this with full functionality which is free, not a trial and can crop/select what part of the login screen you want to snapshot?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Workaround: enable remote desktop on your computer, and use a different computer to take the snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Win 7 Logon Screen Capture](http://sourceforge.net/projects/login7/):

- free
- Windows 7
- take a snapshot of login screen

[image]

[image]

[image]

Result (.jpg file, no choice):

[image]

> How to Use it :-
>
> 1. Open up \Windows\System32
> 2. Look for a file called "Utilman.exe"
> 3. Take ownership the "Utilman.exe" file, and rename it into "Utilman_old.exe"
> 4. Copy the new "Utilman.exe" file that is located in this folder to Windows\System32
> 5. Lock Windows 7, and click on the Ease of Access button.
> 6. Capture the logon screen with ease...
>
> TO RESTORE:
>
> 1. Delete the new "Utilman.exe"
> 2. Rename the "Utilman_old.exe" into "Utilman.exe"
> 3. And you are done...

Other solutions: [How can I take a screenshot of my logon screen in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/158976/116475):

- some [Windows tweaking](https://superuser.com/a/293567/116475)
- [WinBubbles](http://blog.unlockforus.org/2010/01/winbubbles-2010-customize-and-tweak.html) (requires a multi-monitor setup)